# Can I safely delete sw.old folder on my MacBookPro?

Tags: macos, mac

Can I safely delete sw.old folder on my MacBookPro ?
I'd like to get rid of all redundant software, and this looks like it.
Can I safely proceed and delete this folder ?

Comment: Where is this sw.old folder located on your hard drive? Can you list its contents?

Comment: I think it is a Finkproject leftover, as it contains a "fink" folder.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.finkproject.org/ installs in `/sw`, so this may be a leftover of using that in the past. You might want to check your `.bashrc` etc to see whether any paths still point to that folder, but it's most probably safe to remove.

What I usually do in such cases it to rename the directory (e.g. `sudo mv /sw.old /sw.old-DELETE-IN-SEPT-2019`) and then wait a month to see if something breaks.